# OpenSSH internal-sftp not accepting allowed/denied_requests

Tags: ssh, security, configuration, sftp, hardening

Trying to set up a highly restricted SFTP server with OpenSSH_7.4p1 for remote scripts to upload data. The goal is a black hole where the scripts can do a "put" with user level keys and no other server commands are possible. Everything worked fine until the final step where I tried to the limit the `sftp` command set using `-P` and `-p` options in this `sshd_config` `Match` clause:

```
Match user globalstat
    ChrootDirectory /inbound
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -d data -p put -P df,pwd,rm,mkdir,rmdir,get,rename,symlink
```

Tried a variety of combinations, but `-P` for `denied_requests` never blocks any of the specified remote commands. Applying `allowed_requests` with `-p put` or `put,cd` breaks the transfer and returns *"Couldn't canonicalise: Permission denied Need cwd"*. Without `-P` or `-p`, there is no problem with the writes, and based on other postings for this error, I'm pretty sure my directory permissions are correct. I've been using this man page for a reference:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sftp-server.8.html

It implies that `Subsystem` rather than `ForceCommand` is the place for these options, but they don't work in the main body of `sshd_config` and restarting sshd throws an error if `Subsystem` is used in a `Match` clause instead of `ForceCommand`.

I really hope it's possible to get this working and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `-p`/`-P` are names of low-level *SFTP protocol requests*. Not the high-level OpenSSH `sftp` *client commands*.

These are the names: `open`, `close`, `read`, `write`, `lstat`, `fstat`, `setstat`, `fsetstat`, `opendir`, `readdir`, `remove`, `mkdir`, `rmdir`, `realpath`, `stat`, `rename`, `readlink`, `symlink`, `posix-rename`, `statvfs`, `fstatvfs`, `hardlink`, `fsync`, `lsetstat`.

You can get the up to date list by running `sftp-server -Q requests`, as [`sftp-server` man page says](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server#P).

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. Somehow I interpreted "requests" as a parameter instead of a literal... my bad. So far, these denies have achieved most of the hardening I was looking for: `ForceCommand internal-sftp -d data -P lstat,fstat,setstat,fsetstat,remove,mkdir,rmdir,stat,rename,readlink,symlink,posix-rename,hardlink,fsync`. I'll continue to work with it to see if any other denies can be added before breaking the upload. Again, thanks for your reply and getting me into the right galaxy with these options.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the question has already been answered, I'll just mention an issue which originally led me here:

Even though the `internal-sftp ...` expression looks like a normal command, double quotes do not appear to be handled as usual. This won't work for `mkdir` and `symlink`:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp -l INFO -P "mkdir,rmdir,ln,symlink"
```

This will:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp -l INFO -P mkdir,rmdir,ln,symlink
```